# Convert some columns of objects to json string

Tags: json, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I want to convert some columns of a dataframe to json strings. I was hoping that something like the following would work but apply+json.dumps can't operate on a Series.

```
jcols = ['a','c']
df[jcols] = df[jcols].apply(json.dumps, axis=1).astype('string')
```

The following code DOES work but there must be a more straightforward way. The code uses list comprehension, Series, map(), dict to create a new dataframe containing the json string columns. What am I missing?

```
d = {'d':0}
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[d,d,d],'b':[21,22,23],'c':[d,d,d]})
display(df,df.dtypes)
jcols = ['a','c']
jdf = pd.DataFrame({c:(df[c].map(json.dumps).astype('string') if c in jcols else df[c]) for c in df.columns})
display(jdf,jdf.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap) instead:

```
df[jcols] = df[jcols].applymap(json.dumps).astype('string')
```

`df`:

```
          a   b         c
0  {"d": 0}  21  {"d": 0}
1  {"d": 0}  22  {"d": 0}
2  {"d": 0}  23  {"d": 0}
```

`df.dtypes`:

```
a    string
b     int64
c    string
dtype: object
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

import json

d = {'d': 0}
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [d, d, d], 'b': [21, 22, 23], 'c': [d, d, d]})
jcols = ['a', 'c']

df[jcols] = df[jcols].applymap(json.dumps).astype('string')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Well done. You earned the accepted answer. I now understand why applymap() is a thing. So rare that the first answer is completely correct. Must be today's eclipse.

Comment: @BSalita, How it Cast a pandas object to a specified Json dtype?  this is again casting it to string only while using `astype('string')` , Isn't it? However, its true in a sense if you have data as `json.dumps`  form.

Comment: `json` is a _standard_ often represented as a contiguous block of text. [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) is converting a python `dict` to a valid JSON (of type `str` as that is the type that fits in with python types). This would be normally considered type `object` in the DataFrame without the additional type cast with `astype`. There is no JSON dtype as JSON is not a type. @kulfi

Comment: @kulfi Yes, `astype` is making the `dtype` into `string`. Without `astype`, the `dtype` is `object`. I believe that's a legacy issue with pandas.

Comment: @HenryEcker, thanks for explaining just learning though :-).

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be very simplistic:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[d,d,d],'b':[21,22,23],'c':[d,d,d]})
>>> df
          a   b         c
0  {'d': 0}  21  {'d': 0}
1  {'d': 0}  22  {'d': 0}
2  {'d': 0}  23  {'d': 0}
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b     int64
c    object
```

Simply without importing `json` it can be:

```
>>> df[jcols] = df[jcols].astype('string')
>>> df.dtypes
a    string
b     int64
c    string
dtype: object
```

Or even simpler if there are limited columns to change:

```
>>> df.astype({'a': 'string', 'c': 'string'}).dtypes
a    string
b     int64
c    string
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is a clever answer for some situations. However, it doesn't produce valid `json` as requested. It is round-trippable with `df[jcols] = df[jcols].applymap(ast.literal_eval)`.

Comment: @BSalita  true, I agree.